# Algorithm: Current day of week is always #2 in order

Tags: algorithms

sum up: I want to create an algorithm (or two) where the outcome is a list of numbers (1-7) where #2 is today, #1 is yesterday and #3.. is tomorrow and thereafter.

For example;

> If today is **Wednesday (3)**
>   1. Monday = 7
>   2. Tuesday = 1
>   3. Wednesday = 2
>   4. Thursday = 3
>   5. Friday = 4
>
> and if today is **Friday (5)**
>    - Monday = 5
>    - Tuesday = 6
>    - Wednesday = 7
>    - Thursday = 1
>    - Friday = 2

**Limitation:**
The only numbers you can calculate with are

- The number of the week (i.e. Tuesday = 2, Friday = 5)
- 'Today', as a variable (i.e. if Today = Wednesday, Today = 3)

i.e.

> NewNumber = **7** - (***today*** +  ***WeekDay***)

*Above probably doesn't makes sense, but for demonstration of variables only.*

I'd agree with two algorithms, one for every day from today until end of week, and one for the past days (i.e. if today =  Wednesday, #1 applies to wed-sun and #2 applies to mon-tue).

What would be the correct algorithm for this matter?

Comment: Didn't you just describe your algorithm? What exactly is holding you up?

Comment: The above algorithm is false. If today is Wednesday and the algorithm is used for Monday, then that equals  7-(3+1)=4, as it should be 7, according to the earlier mentioned scheme. Aside of that, for Friday  → 7-(3+5) = -8, while it should become 4.

Comment: Your *formula* clearly is wrong, but you described (with words) precisely what your algorithm is meant to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use modulus to "wrap" around the week.

In your notation:

$NewNumber = (1 + WeekDay - today) ~ \%  ~ 7 + 1$

where $x ~ \% ~ 7$ ist the remainder when dividing $x$ by $7$.

You can also use

$NewNumber = (8 + WeekDay - today) ~ \%  ~ 7 + 1$

which avoids remainders of negative numbers.

Comment: Could you add a written out calculation of that equation for Tuesday, where Today = Friday for example? i.e. Tuesday (new=6) = (1 + 2 - 5).. ? Just so I completely understand the second part.. :)

Comment: (1 + 2 - 5) % 7 + 1 = (-2 % 7) + 1 = 5 + 1 = 6. If you want to avoid negative numbers in front of the %, change the formula to NewNumber = (8 + WeekDay - today) % 7 + 1.

Comment: Thanks, I never knew Modulo, so that is where my problem was in understanding. I don't see how the first formula results in negative numbers. I just did 10 different calculations with different Today and weekdays, and never ended up with negative numbers. Nevertheless, your formula, or actually the %7 modulus thingy, solved my problem. Both of them in fact! :)

Answer (score 1):

Let these numbers represent the days (absolutely, by name):

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline \text{weekday} & \text{#}\\
\hline\text{Monday} & 1 \\
\text{Tuesday} & 2 \\
\text{Wednesday} & 3 \\
\text{Thursday} & 4 \\
\text{Friday} & 5 \\
\text{Saturday} & 6 \\
\text{Sunday} & 7 \\\hline
\end{array}$$
And let the current day be denoted $T$ (from that table).

Then the algorithm you're looking for is $\boxed{f(d) = 1+(4+T+d)\%7}.$

For example, if today is Tuesday, $T = 2$. Say I wanted what day it was yesterday: then $f(1) = 1+(4+2+1)\%7 = 1+0 = 1$, which corresponds to Monday, the correct answer.

Comment: As much as I wanted to say "That's amazing", since I noticed you put in a lot of effort.. I have to say "your formula is wrong". In my opening post, I stated that "If today equals Wednesday, Wednesday equals 2 (after calculation)". Applying that to your formula; 1+(4+3+3)%7 = 4, not 2. Another attempt. If today is Friday and I want to get Tuesday, I'd apply 1+(4+5+2)%7, I get 5, not 6. Nevertheless, Cuija, below, offered a complete working solution. Feel free to elaborate how yours is actually working or update your formula. Love to learn more about this :)

Comment: I think the disconnect is that I have given the inverse of what you were asking for: plugging in today to $d$ yields $2$, yesterday yields $1$, tomorrow yields $3$, etc. I will add the reverse of the formula.

Comment: In general, I needed two formulas. 1 that states 'Today = 2', the second of the week-order. The other one should state "today = 0 and yesterday = -1". Theoretically, you did correct, but the outcome should've been different.. :) The first formula of Cuija did completely correct, whereas I only needed to change the +1 to -1 (at the end) for the second formula that I required. I never knew the modulo, but that was the key to solving my question :)